# synergy windows -> mac - command-space usage

Tags: mac, synergy

I have synergy running as a server on windows 7, with a client on Mac OS X 10.6.4.

I have key mapped Alt -> Super and Super -> Alt.

When i move the mouse to the mac, i hold the windows key and press space.  If i have the mac keyboard viewer showing, it indicates that i am pressing command and space.  However, spotlight does not open, and instead the grey window that opens when you hold control and space opens.

If i instead press control and space, the same grey window opens.

How i can get the spotlight menu to open over synergy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated to the latest unstable 1.5.0 version of the synergy client for mac.  this not only fixes this problem but adds support for the shift key which is missing from the latest stable version

**UPDATE:** Actually, the best client version for mac is attached to [this](http://synergy-foss.org/pm/issues/2763) bug report, which adds support for correct command mapping (alt->super and super->alt does not need to be performed) and double-click support.